# ADFS should I configure a Relying Party Trust?

Tags: c#, active-directory, wif, ws-federation

Not sure about this so I will try and give as much detail as possible.

We are a Microsoft outfit, so when it came to building a federated security model, we of course have used ADFS (running on a Windows 2012 R2 server).

This works well, but we have come across a need to place a system in a country where by they use a different federation system. Not sure what it is at the moment, by my question. I am assuming that the best way of completing this without changing any code will be to install our system and then create a replying party trust between both federation system.

Setting up a replying party trust in ADFS, would we need to change the login process, or will the relying trust deal with this automatically?

Currently we use the GivenName and Surname to display account details, would we need to bring these fields into the ADFS system or would this be dealt with automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear from you post whether you are using the 3rd party federation system as an IDP or to consume identities from it. Based on this, you would do one of the following

If the 3rd party system is an IDP, you would add a CP Trust in ADFS to point to it. You would establish a contract for the claim types that it would send to you. Note that this can be any claim URI that logically contains the information you need from the 3rd party IDP. Then in the CP Trust Issuance acceptance rules, you would "normalize" this to what you need for your apps that your current AD Authority does for you.

If the 3rd party is something that you are the IDP for which then goes to the app, you would create a RP trust. You would also agree on the contract that the 3rd party system needs and then issue the claim type to it based on the agreement in the issuance claims rules for that RP trust.

Hope that clarifies.

Thanks
//Sam

Comment: There is yet another possibility, configuring trust between the other IdP and the RP with no ADFS at all. This was my first impression after reading the question. +1 anyway.

Comment: "that the best way of completing this without changing any code will be to install our system". You don't need to install another instance of ADFS - just federate the existing one.